# Autentication error using google script to search twitter usernames

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been using the following google script to follow twitter users, which works fine.

```
var twitterKeys= {
 TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: "xxx",
 TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: "xxxx",
 TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: "xxxx",
 TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET: "xxxx"    
};

var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

props.setProperties(twitterKeys);

var twit = new Twitter.OAuth(props);

var service = new Twitter.OAuth(props);

if ( service.hasAccess() ) {


var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json';
var payload = {
  screen_name: 'username',
};

var response = service.fetch(url, {
  method: 'post',
  payload: payload
});

var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)); 

} 

}
```

I would now like to search twitter usernames and so followed the information given here:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search

I amended my code by changing the API url, changing the payload and changing the method from 'post' to 'get'.

Here's the code I have now:

```
var twitterKeys= {
 TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: "xxx",
 TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: "xxxx",
 TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: "xxxx",
 TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET: "xxxx"    
};

var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

props.setProperties(twitterKeys);

var twit = new Twitter.OAuth(props);

var service = new Twitter.OAuth(props);

if ( service.hasAccess() ) {
var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json';
var payload = {
  q: 'test',
};
var response = service.fetch(url, {
  method: 'get',
  payload: payload
});
var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)); 

} 

}
```

It's not working and I get the following error:

Request failed for https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 450, file "Service", project "Twitter lib")

I've amended this code in similar ways a few times now (for example to mute users) and it's worked well.

Any ideas why it's failing?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the URL you are making the fetch to, according to the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search) for `GET users/search`, the `q` parameter needs to be sent in the request as `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=searchTerm`.

The fetch request you posted does not send the request with the correct format. You can get around this by manually setting the `q` parameter in the fetch request:

```js
var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json'
var username = 'username'
var q = '?q=' + username

var response = service.fetch(url + q, {
  method: 'get',
  });    

var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```